# Changing images of toolbar buttons dynamicaly

Tags: uikit, uitoolbar, iphone

I have a tool bar with buttons whose image is set to a particular image.When the user clicks a button in the main view, i want to change the image of one of the toolbar buttons to another image.I tried many methods.Everything ran without errors, but none showed any change in toolbar.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tutorial for this:
[How-to-change-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-the-iphone-toolbar](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/04/17/how-to-change-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-the-iphone-toolbar/)

This is a great tutorial because it goes over changing the images based on state as well.

Comment: I did it on my own,although not without some head scratching

Comment: Care to enlighten the rest of us?